# Closing the Selector when server is shutting down

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, selector, nio

When I want to close the server, I will need to close Selector which is blocking the Thread. So, I call `selector.close()` from the main thread which helps to unblock `selector.select();` But the selector doesn't throw `ClosedSelectorException` exception as it was supposed to I guess:

```
while (true) {

    try {

        // Blocks until a 'socket' is ready registered with selector is ready.
        selector.select();
    } 
    catch (ClosedSelectorException ex) {

        // Never reached?
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {

        // Never reached?  
        ex.printStackTrace();

    }

    // ...
```

But rather it throws the exception at the later lines:

`Set<SelectionKey> readyKeys = selector.selectedKeys();`

So I want to do two things:

- Detect if the selector was closed when select() unblocks. (possible?)
- After that I want to break from the `while(true)` and let the thread stop.

And should I use a boolean flag, interrupt the thread, or break from loop?

Comment: Have you tried to return from the exception handler? The loop will continue to the next method which will throw an unhandled ClosedSelectorException because the selector has been closed already.

Comment: Just put the `...` inside the `try` bock.

Comment: @EJP Wouldn't that result in the program printing out an exception log?

Comment: No, it will result in 'never reached' being reached in the `catch (ClosedSelector)` block, in which you can do anything you like.

Comment: @EJP What I was trying to say is that if the `selector` is closed before we proceeds to do any work, nothing should happen and the thread should end. If the `selector` is closed after we proceeds to do some work, it is an exceptional case. The former is not really an exceptional scenario and we shouldn't use a side effect (exception occurring on performing operations using a closed selector)  as a means to exit the thread.

Comment: If the selector is closed it is because you closed it. There is no other cause. If you closed it 'exceptionally' somewhere you should log it there; if you closed it 'normally' you don't need to log it at all, or you can log it differently: whatever you want. Inmbthbcases this `catch` will catch it, whereupon you just `break. Your remark about not using a 'side effect' is just pointless attitudinizing

Comment: @Ejp: Do you mean `try { ... }` and for what purpose? `Selector` doesn't throw `ClosedSelectorException` it just unblocks on `close()`. Can someone tell me what's going on?

Comment: @user963241 We were discussing whether you should simply add a 'break' in the catch statement and let the use of a closed selector result in an exception that will move the control to the catch block where you can do whatever you want before you break out of the loop there. I don't like this approach so I am arguing against it and providing an alternate solution in my answer. You can wait for other answer if you like

Comment: @EJP We will just have to agree to disagree on this.

Comment: CKing: But the exception doesn't occur when the selector wakes up. So, that would means I will need to wait for the failure to occur in the next lines when I use the selector for say `selectedKeys` which must be put under a try catch block. i.e. `try { selector.selectedKeys(); } catch(ClosedSelectorException ) { // catch here and break }`

Comment: However, I prefer your approach as well but still if `try catch` does it for me for free (Just because it's good to catch every exception that can occur?) then I don't see why I should check it manually if selector was closed.

Comment: An `Exception` usually indicates that something went wrong. If a server shutdown is requested while `selector.getKeys` was being executed, you go to the catch block and print the error indicating that a close was requested while some work was being done and then `break`.  If a server shutdown was requested when the `selector` was waiting on the `select`  method, there was no work being done anyway so why treat it as an exception and print the error when the shutdown was graceful? Why not just exit gracefully then and there?

Comment: The previous comment assumes that you will move the call to `selectedKeys` inside the same `try catch` where `selector.select` is being called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I want to do two things:
>
> Detect if the selector was closed when select() unblocks. (possible?)
>
> After that I want to break from the while(true) and let the thread
> stop.

If you take a look at the docs for the [close](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Selector.html#close()) method in `Selector`, you will see that it says that the `close` method calls `wakeup` which will make the current `Selector` (if waiting) to return immediately.
If you take a look at the docs for `Selector`,, you will see that it has a method called [isOpen](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Selector.html#isOpen()).

> public abstract boolean isOpen()
>
> Tells whether or not this selector is open.

All you need to do is to check if `selector.isOpen()` returns false immediately after you call `selector.select()` and simply `break` out of your while loop if it returns false. You should also move any code that uses the `selector` inside the `try-catch` block. There is no need to have a separate `boolean` flag to achieve this. This is how your modified code should look :

```
    try {

       // Blocks until a 'socket' is ready registered with selector is ready.
        selector.select();
        if(!selector.isOpen()) {
            break;//graceful exit since selector was not in use anyway
        }
        Set<SelectionKey> readyKeys = selector.selectedKeys();
        // ...        
    
     } catch (ClosedSelectorException ex) {

        // selector was closed while being used
        ex.printStackTrace();
     } catch (IOException ex) {

        // some other exception
        ex.printStackTrace();
       
    }
```

The advantage of using `isOpen` is that you will now be able to identify whether your server was shutdown gracefully (no error printed) or it was shutdown in between some activity on the `selector` (error printed)

The assumption here is that the `whie(true)` loop is defined inside the run method of your `Thread`.

Comment: That's much better. On one hand you can inform that "selector was normally closed" and also "selector was exceptionally closed" but I am not sure if there will ever be a case of `ClosedSelectorException`.

Comment: Where and when do you `close` the `selector`?. Can you guarantee that other developers who work with your code will not accidently `close` the `selector` while it is doing some work?

Comment: Okay, I see now. The selector could be closed after `isOpen` is executed. That's when exception will be useful. I close it from main thread to stop the server thread.

Comment: Precisely. Glad that you finally understood what I was rambling about :)